# Efficient way to register client-side json from server-side asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I wrote an aspx page. I want to register a client var from the code behind (c#) **directly to the markup**. Meaning no communication is needed.

I have converted some user-defined object to json object on the server side,
and the client (jquery) expects to use json obejct var. 
So I prefer as little conversions as possible (not converting to string and than parsing to json on the client side).

What is the most efficient and elegant way to do so ?

Comment: Could you clarify this sentence: "I have a json object on the server side already"? What type of the object that you want to pass to client-side?

Comment: If you are writing to the markup, then var myJsonObject = {yourServerObjectHere}. But you could also manage all JSON form some single instance object with function MyJSONStorage.addJson('objectKey',{yourServerObjectHere});

Comment: JSON Page Methods are your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I follow your question, but apparently, you are looking to write a javascript variable from server side; something like:

```
var json = @"var myobj={""Name"":""John Smith"",""Age"",34};";
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myvar", json,true);
```

This will render this on client-side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var myobj={"Name":"John Smith","Age",34};//]]>
</script>
```